# How to increase the xyz axis length or size of graph in scatter plot matlab?

Tags: matlab

scatter3:

[image: scatter3]

How to increase x0,y0,z0 length in scatter3 plot?

Comment: See [`axis`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html). In the graph you linked, you can for example try `axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2])`